# Adding descriptions to arguments in User-defined functions

Tags: excel, vba

Whenever I type in the name of a "built-in" Excel function (SUMIF, for example), a guide will pop up saying something like "(range, criteria, [sum_range])", describing the arguments that the function will accept. Is there a way to add similar names to arguments in my own user-defined functions, so that the same type of guide will appear?

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer: Application.MacroOptions will do what you want -- but only when the function is invoked via the insert function dialog. It doesn't seem to work when you just type =funcname(  directly in a cell. The following page has a nice example of how to use it:

http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/user-defined_function_argument_descriptions_in_excel_2010/